# How to preg_match country phone number code

Tags: php

How can i get only the phone number without country code or white space ?

the one i tried also remve 359 in middle of the phone number

The code can be 359 or +359 or 00359 or +00359

02 is city code and i need to remove the 0 that why i did (int)

```
<?php
$string = '+00359 02 359 10969';
$string = str_replace(" ", '', $string);
$string = (int)preg_replace("/(?:359)/", '', $string);

echo  $string;
```

output is

```
210969
```

Should be

```
235910969
```

Comment: don't remove it in the regex, remove it after it has been extracted instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic is more complex that you might think.
I would suggest to go with google phone library
https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

Answer (score 0):

Usually country codes changes but basically last 10 number is local number but in your example you don't want first 0 too so totally 9 numbers so simply you can use like below.

```
$string = '+00359 02 359 10969';
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
$string = substr($string, -9);

echo  $string; // Output: 235910969
```

Otherwise you have to define all country codes, check and remove all of them from start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the result you need:

```
'\^\+(?:00359\s0)\' or '\^\+?(00359|359|00359)\s0\'
```

Answer (score 0):

if the format is always `+`+`country code`+`space`+`rest of phone number`, you could just use explode()

```
$string = '+00359 02 359 10969';
$string = explode(" ",$string,2)[1]; // -> 02 359 10969
```

> 02 is city code and i need to remove the 0 that why i did (int)

ltrim?

```
$string = '+00359 02 359 10969';
$string = explode(" ",$string,2)[1]; // -> 02 359 10969
$string = ltrim($string,'0'); // -> 2 359 10969
```